# images of the world we have at our disposal

Tags: meaning-in-context

Does in the following sentence "***images of the world we have at our disposal***" refer to *our understanding of the world* or *our photographs of the world*? I think the former should be OK. Am I right?

> Such mild delight in detritus is in direct contradiction to the ever
>   more sophisticated, clean and perfect images of the world we have at
>   our disposal as a result of the widespread application of digital
>   technologies that now seem essential to all human production, in art
>   and, of course, in science, images which seem to present an ideal
>   rather than a messy reality.

Comment: Sian Ede, right?  How does mild delight in detritus contradict perfect images?  Suppose she'd said "fervid despair in detritus aligns with flawed images"?  Would that make any more or less sense?  You won't be right until you realize this stuff has no discernible meaning.

Comment: @deadrat It is easy for native speakers to identify where the speech is intentionally aimed to have no meaning or to be ambiguous. But, for non-native speakers it is not that easy. So, please understand me whenever I ask about such contents. It is also hard for a non-native speaker to specify the degree of the ambiguity of a text, naturally. Any way, clues from natives always make things clearer.

Comment: I hope you don't think my ongoing comments about Sian Ede's writing are in any way a criticism of your questions.  But I'm afraid you're incorrect about two things.  The first is that Ede is being intentionally ambiguous.  She's not; she's thinks she's being illuminating.  The second is that native speakers find it easy to identify such nonsense writing.  Many can't, especially those who labor in the fields of post-modernism -- lit crit, social studies, cultural studies, etc.  Look up "Alan Sokal *Social Text*"  I hope you don't mind my asking, but why are you reading this?

Comment: @deadrat Sian Ede may sound ambiguous or pretentious, but she only expresses her personal understanding of art_ true or false, clear or ambiguous, and faithfully or pretentiously. Her insights are interesting for me any way. And, I always respect your enlightening ideas, suggestions, and recommendations :)

Comment: As dismissive as I've been of an author you find insightful, you're kind to express your respect.  I have no problem with ambiguity or pretentiousness.  I'm guilty of those sins as well.  My problem is that Ede doesn't express thoughts discernible from the language she uses.  Part of this arises from her abyssal ignorance of science; part, from her carelessness in composition.  Her insights are thus hidden behind a welter of inappropriate verbiage, and what you have left are your own insights into what you think her insights may be.

Comment: Well, sorry, that last was pretty pretentious, not to mention tendentious.  But I trust it wasn't ambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

I think "at our disposal" refers to the "perfect images".

We have them at our disposal "as a result of the widespread application of digital technologies". **So it's high-resolution ("perfect") digital images we are talking about here.**